# general php syntax

Tags: php, syntax

how do i put this `<?php echo $cfs->get('exclude'); ?>` within the double quotes in this `<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery exclude=""]'); ?>`

meaning, what is the correct syntax to merge the two? i attempted to read through some of [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_syntax.asp) to solve it, but have little php knowledge.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sprintf('[gallery exclude="%s"]', $cfs->get('exclude'));
```

See [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf)

Also readable:

```
$exclude = $cfs->get('exclude');
"[gallery exclude=\"$exclude\"]";
```

Comment: OP, do it this way -- its good practice to know how to `sprintf`

Answer (score 0):

this is one way

```
echo do_shortcode('[gallery exclude="' . $cfs->get('exclude') . '"]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[gallery exclude='$cfs->get('exclude')]'); ?>
```

Comment: i'm not sure, if this works - you have to put {} arround the Expression - btw. string is closed with " instead of '